# formik setErrors reseting the other fields

Tags: reactjs, formik

I have a form where i am using formik with the validations like

```
const formik = useFormik({
  enableReinitialize: true,
  initialValues: {
    name: insurer && get(insurer, "name", null),
    surname: insurer && get(insurer, "surname", null),
    postalCode: insurer && get(insurer, "postalCode", null),
  },

  onSubmit: (values: any) => {},
  validationSchema: Yup.object().shape({
    name: Yup.string()
      .typeError("Preenche este campo")
      .required("Preenche este campo"),
    surname: Yup.string()
      .typeError("Preenche este campo")
      .required("Preenche este campo"),
  }),
});
```

As you can see i have three fields name, surename and postalCode, where i also have defined validation for name and surname, for postalCode, i am hitting an api which is returns false for invalid postalCode

So when initially i submit the form i see error of

```
Object { surname: "Preenche este campo", name: "Preenche este campo" }
```

Now if i start typing the postal code i receive error from api and then i set this like

```
formik.setErrors({postalCode:'error in postal code' });
```

but now when i console log

```
console.log(formik.errors)
```

I only see error for this field, and the other field error are resetted

```
Object { postalCode: "error in postal code" }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`formik.setErrors` is applied to all errors, `{postalCode:'error in postal code' }` is only a particular error of many other errors, so when you set it singularly that has wiped out all other fields' errors.

In this case, you should pass the other fields' errors `formik.errors` to that function along with your updated error.

```
formik.setErrors({ ...formik.errors, postalCode:'error in postal code' });
```

Comment: my bad, didn't struck it to me :)